# Aws comprehend Custom entity

Tags: amazon-web-services, machine-learning, nlp, training-data

I was able to train custom entities in aws comprehend but as per AWS docs transfer learning is done when you train a custom entity is mentioned .Does it really happening coz my custom entity is not recognizing the entities which is done by predefined entity analyzer

Answer (score 0):

you need to give more information before anyone can answer you. Which method did you use to perform your customer entity recognition task? Was it using entity list or annotation?

Comment: AM using entity list to perform the custom entity recognition training.....now can you answer